# how to fetch value of multiple text-area boxes and store in a database on click of submit button

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express, materialize

I want to get the value of all text-area boxes and store into database on click of submit button.
Multiple text-area's are appearing on click of add button.

I am using nodejs, express and mongodb.

I have one select field and two textarea's. i am able to post the first values of textarea's on submit.
But if i want to post multiple textarea values on submit (multiple textarea's will appear on click of respective add/plus button), I am unable to post it.

Also i am facing an issue while creating the same template of textarea box but with delete button. The textarea is appearing below submit button.
Can anyone help me out?

Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h5> New updates/Notifications </h5>
        <div class="input-field col s11">
            <select class="moduleSelect" id="getOptionValue">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Module</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s11">
            <textarea id="textarea updateTextarea" name="updateTextarea" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            <label for="textarea">Update area</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s1 addButtonUpdate">
            <i class="material-icons small icon-demo">add_circle</i>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s11 notificationField">
            <textarea id="textarea notificationTextarea" name="notificationTextarea" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            <label for="textarea">Notification area</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s1 addButtonNotify">
            <i class="material-icons small icon-demo">add_circle</i>
        </div>

        <div class="col s6 right buttonGroup ">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn submitButton">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getOptions = ajaxServices("/iotsupport/modules/getModules", "GET");
    if (getOptions.status == 201) {
        for (var i in getOptions.body) {
            var option = getOptions.body[i].moduleName;
            var optionDiv = document.createElement('option');
            optionDiv = $(optionDiv).text(option);
            $('.moduleSelect').append(optionDiv);
        }
    } else if (getOptions.status == 401) {
        swal({
            title: "",
            text: "Error fetching the query options",
            icon: "error",
            button: "OK"
        })
    }
    $('select').material_select();

    $(".submitButton").on('click', function(e) {
        var optionList = $("select[id='getOptionValue']").val();
        console.log(optionList);
        var updateFieldValue = $("textarea[name='updateTextarea']").val();
        var notificationField = $("textarea[name='notificationTextarea']").val();
        var sendObject = {
            "moduleName": optionList,
            "updateObject": updateFieldValue,
            "notifyObject": notificationField
        }
        var responseObject = ajaxServices("/iotsupport/addUpdateNotify/postUpdateNotify", "POST", sendObject);
        console.log(responseObject);
        if (responseObject.status == 401) {
            alert("some error occured")
        } else if (responseObject.status == 201) {
            alert("update/notification is done.");
            location.reload();
        }
    });

    $(".addButtonUpdate").on('click', function(e) {
        var n = 8 // adjust it in some way
        var inputArea = ['<div class=" col s11 materialize-textarea input-field col s' + n + '">',
            '<textarea class="input-field materialize-textarea" rows="3" id="cloneTextarea" name="cloneTextarea textArea-' + n + '">',
            'update area',
            '</textarea></div>'
        ].join('')
        $('.row').append(inputArea);
        console.log(inputArea);
    });

    $(".addButtonNotify").on('click', function(e) {
        var n = 8 // adjust it in some way
        var inputArea = ['<div class="col s11 materialize-textarea input-field col s' + n + '">',
            '<textarea class="input-field materialize-textarea" rows="3" id="textArea-' + n + '">',
            'Notify area',
            '</textarea></div>'
        ].join('')
        $('.row').append(inputArea);
        console.log(inputArea);
    });
});
```

Please refer to this image

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> The textarea is appearing below submit button.

To mitigate this issue change below line in your js

```
$('.row').append(inputArea);
```

To

```
$('.buttonGroup').before(inputArea);
```

Please clarify other queries so I can update my answer.

> I am able to post the first values of textarea's on submit. But if i
>   want to post multiple textarea values on submit?

For this query if I am getting you right you want to save all the textarea's value in DB. And here you have dynamic textareas.

Simplest way is to take a form. In your AJAX you just have to serialize the form to get all the possible values of textareas.

```
$("#formId").searialize();
```

Use this code on submit button call. On server side you will be able to access all the data in `req.body`

Hope this is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few classes which i have added in my HTML structure.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/frameworks/materialize.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/IoTSupport/updateNotification.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h5> New updates/Notifications </h5>
        <div class="input-field col s11">
            <select class="moduleSelect" id="getOptionValue">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Module</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <div class="input-field col s11 updateField">
            <textarea id="textarea updateTextarea" name="updateTextarea" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            <label for="textarea">Update area</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s1 addButtonUpdate">
            <i class="material-icons small icon-demo" id="add1">add_circle</i>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s11 notificationField">
            <textarea id="textarea notificationTextarea" name="notificationTextarea" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            <label for="textarea">Notification area</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s1 addButtonNotify">
            <i class="material-icons small icon-demo" id="add2">add_circle</i>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 right buttonGroup ">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn submitButton">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/IoTSupport/ajaxCalls/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/frameworks/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/IoTSupport/updateNotification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There are few changes in my Javascript file. The main piece of code to fetch all the textarea value is below:

make use of an array in order to iterate completely
updateField = [];

```
**$("textarea[name='updateTextarea']").each(function () {
    var collectValue = ($(this).val())
    updateField.push(collectValue)
 })**
```

Comment: This is an improvement in question or an answer?? If it is a question please update the question itself.